# sql query doesn't return enough rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I having trouble figuring out this SQL Query (MySql 5 is the server).

My tables are related like this:

[image]

My Query looks like this:

```
select 
    tblCustomer.customerNo,
    tblSalesHeader.invoiceNo,
    tblSalesHeader.orderDate,
    tblSalesDetail.quantity,
    tblSalesDetail.productNo,
    tblSalesDetail.description,
    tblSalesDetail.unitPrice
FROM
  tblSalesHeader
   left JOIN tblSalesDetail ON (tblSalesHeader.invoiceNo = tblSalesDetail.invoiceNo)
   left JOIN tblCustomer ON (tblSalesHeader.cID = tblCustomer.cid)
   left JOIN tblUsers ON (tblSalesHeader.salesmanID = tblUsers.iID)
   left JOIN tblProducts ON (tblSalesDetail.productNo = tblProducts.productNumber)

WHERE
  tblSalesHeader.invoiceNo=2482
GROUP BY
  tblCustomer.customerNo,
  tblSalesHeader.invoiceNo,
  tblSalesDetail.productNo
```

I know that there should be 5 rows returned because there are 5 rows in tblSalesDetail where the invoiceNo=2482 like so:

```
select * 
from 
    tblSalesDetail
    left join tblSalesHeader on (tblSalesHeader.invoiceNo = tblSalesDetail.invoiceNo)
where
tblSalesHeader.invoiceNo=2482
```

I'm sure that my joins are filtering results out but I don't know why.

Comment: In order for that join to work, it needs to resolve to a unique row. If you aren't getting the 5 rows you expect, it's because something does not match up in ONE of your joins.  I would suggest taking off the one-ways for a try, and see what you get.

Comment: @Shawn: You're using `GROUP BY` tblSalesHeader.invoiceNo. So it may be easy to get less rows than by your second query. Further `FROM tblSalesHeader LEFT JOIN tblSalesDetails` is not the same as `FROM tblSalesDetails LEFT JOIN tblSalesHeader`, even with the same `ON` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `GROUP BY`. You're not using it.